# Adding an array of functions and randomly selecting one of them

Tags: c++, arrays, xcode, function, compiler-errors

I've been trying for a while to find a way to create an array of functions. I use Xcode, and every time I try, it prompts me with the warning

> Expected "(" for function-style casts or type construction.

I'm not exactly too sure what to do about it. Here is a sample of code.

```
//possibleResponses

int Responses[]{ //this is where the error is.

int possibleResponse1;
{
    cout << "Continue...\n";
    getline (cin, inputc);
}

int possibleResponse2 (0);
{
    cout << "Text" << inputb << ".\n";
    getline (cin, inputd);
}
```

To clarify, I have twenty different possible responses that my program can give. I would like to place these in an array and then randomize the output. It would be excellent if someone could help me (if possible, add sample code, I learn better that way), thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you did with the code you posted, but I am sure it will not compile. I will try to show how to add "an array of functions and randomly selecting one".

```
int function1() { ... } // implementation is irrelevant
int function2(int x) { ... }
int function3(char x) { ... }
```

Client code:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::function<int(void)>> functions; // all functions placed
                                                 // in here take no parameters

functions.push_back(function1);
functions.push_back( []() { return function2(190); } ); // adaptor functor, calling
                                                        // function2 with parameters
                                                        // the adaptor matches the
                                                        // signature of
                                                        // functions::value_type
functions.push_back( []() { return function3('s'); } ); // same as above
```

calling a random function from the sequence:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
static std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // mersene twister
std::uniform_int_distribution<> d(0, functions.size());
auto itr = std::begin(functions);
std::advance(itr, dis(gen)); // advance iterator by random number of positions

(*itr)(); // call the functor
```

or:

```
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
static std::mt19937 gen(rd()); // mersene twister
std::uniform_int_distribution<> d(0, functions.size());
auto index = dis(gen)); // get index in range [0, functions.size())

functions[index]();
```

To keep the code clean, consider placing your response functions in a namespace (at least):

```
namespace responses {
    int function1() { ... } // implementation is irrelevant
    int function2(int x) { ... }
    int function3(char x) { ... }
}
```